# Is RENAME DATABASE no longer available in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, rename, alter

If so, what is the workaround? I have a genuine need for this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Dump the existing database and import into a new one.

Comment: Ideally I'd like this to be fast. I think what you're suggesting would be quite slow.

Comment: @uuuu No, it would be fast enough. How many times do you need to do this?

Comment: Once in a blue moon, but it needs to be fast when I do it.

Comment: @uuuu have you tried it - or are you just assuming it will be slow?

Comment: That's slower than I thought it'd be - how large is your database? If you only need to do this very infrequently I guess the times your experiencing seem fine to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it was removed, and also refer to Michael's answer above.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rename-database.html

Answer (score 0):

No. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/rename-database.html